# VBA Store 1 D array to new row only if unique

Tags: arrays, vba, string-comparison

I'm going to store a lot of text within a worksheet. I've written a sub routine which is comparing the array to the ranges of the Excel worksheet. I'm cycling down the entire worksheet checking values along the way.

Something doesn't seem to be working.

Example Array input is

```
( "Dog" , "Cat" , "6" , "Some string like this" )
```

The `UBound` of this input array could change by the way.

My code doesn't seem to be comparing the 3 fields accurately. 
Maybe something is mixed up with my array counting or if anyone has any better ideas on how to accomplish this I would be grateful of any help.

```
Public Sub storeData(sArray() As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
Dim vLastRow As Integer
Dim vRow As Integer
Dim test As Range
Dim Destination As Range
Dim wl As Worksheets

vRow = 1
vLastRow = Worksheets("word List").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print vLastRow
For vRow = 1 To vLastRow
    RollingCheck = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(sArray)
        Set test = Worksheets("word List").Cells(vRow, i + 1)
        If (Trim(test.text) = Trim(sArray(i)) & Len(test) > 0) Then  
            ' To speed it up I added the len() command in to avoid null string. 
            ' Ideally I wish I could only cycle through rows which have the same 
            ' number of columns to array indicies because this will be dynamic
            RollingCheck = RollingCheck + 1
            Debug.Print CStr(vRow) & CStr(RollingCheck) & _
                Worksheets("word List").Cells(vRow, i + 1).text & "=" & sArray(i)
            If (RollingCheck = UBound(sArray)) Then
                MsgBox "exit" & CStr(vRow)
                ' All columns of the worksheet = each index of the array 
                ' thus exit the sub
                Exit Sub 
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next vRow

' Value no found through cycling the work sheet, 
' thus store the array within the next blank row
Set Destination = Worksheets("Word List").Range("A" & vRow)
Set Destination = Destination.Resize(1, UBound(sArray))
Destination.value = sArray
MsgBox "store" & CStr(vRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be simpler to implement if you could rely on not needing to Trim() the data on the worksheet....

```
Public Sub storeData(sArray() As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vLastRow As Integer
    Dim vRow As Integer
    Dim wl As Worksheet, rw As Range, haveMatch As Boolean

    Set wl = Worksheets("word List")

    vLastRow = wl.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print vLastRow

    For vRow = 1 To vLastRow
        Set rw = wl.Rows(vRow)
        'is this a candidate row?
        If Trim(rw.Cells(1).Value) = Trim(sArray(0)) And _
               Application.CountA(rw) = UBound(sArray) + 1 Then

            haveMatch = True
            For i = 1 To UBound(sArray)
                If Trim(rw.Cells(i).Value) <> Trim(sArray(i)) Then
                    haveMatch = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If haveMatch Then Exit Sub

        End If
    Next vRow

    wl.Cells(vLastRow + 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(sArray) + 1).Value = sArray
    MsgBox "stored: " & CStr(vLastRow + 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim Williams is right about those `Trim` functions.

I'm proposing a second answer because it looks as if you might be looking for a match of all your array items in any order and that some of the array items are empty or null strings (which are not to be counted?).

You should also avoid the `.Text` property as that will display only what is visible in the sheet cell. So #### could be a possible value, for example.

A final point is that if your Excel sheet is large and you are testing many arrays, then reading values from that sheet each time is fairly time consuming. You could be better off reading them into some sort of data storage object and testing the existence of your values against that. You'll see that I've used a `Collection`.

All in all, then, your code could be like so ... First create a `Sub` in your module that reads the data into a Module-level variable:

```
Option Explicit
Private mSheetData As Collection

Private Sub ReadExcelData()
    Dim sheetArr As Variant
    Dim lineData As Collection
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    'Read the Excel sheet into a collection - you could be more sophisticated than UsedRange
    sheetArr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("word List").UsedRange.Value2
    Set mSheetData = New Collection
    For r = 1 To UBound(sheetArr, 1)
        Set lineData = New Collection
        For c = 1 To UBound(sheetArr, 2)
            If Not IsEmpty(sheetArr(r, c)) Then
                On Error Resume Next 'avoids error if it's a duplicate in the line
                lineData.Add True, Trim(CStr(sheetArr(r, c)))
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next
        If lineData.Count > 0 Then mSheetData.Add lineData
    Next
End Sub
```

Then add a function that tests for the existence of your sample arrays:

```
Private Function HasMatch(inputArr() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim c As Long
    Dim lineData As Collection

    For Each lineData In mSheetData
        For c = LBound(inputArr) To UBound(inputArr)
            If Not IsEmpty(inputArr(c)) Then
                If Len(inputArr(c)) > 0 Then
                    HasMatch = False
                    On Error Resume Next
                    HasMatch = lineData(Trim(CStr(inputArr(c))))
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Not HasMatch Then Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If HasMatch Then Exit Function
    Next

End Function
```

Then you just have a calling routine, like so:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sample() As Variant

    'Read the data into the array
    ReadExcelData

    'Acquire the next blank line
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("word List")
        Set rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With

    'Test your line(s)
    sample = Array("Dog", "Cat", "6", "Some string like this")
    If Not HasMatch(sample) Then
        rng.Resize(, UBound(sample) - LBound(sample) + 1).Value = sample
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1) 'offset the next blank line ready for next input
    End If

End Sub
```